# GAS deploying option "Anyone, Even Anonymous" option is not available

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, publish

I'm trying to use my google script app in the google site which should be publicly available to anyone.
When I'm trying to deploy my google script as a web app (Publish->Deploy as web app), in the "Who has access to the app" field, the "Anyone, Even Anonymous" option is not available. I have only "Only myself" and "Anyone within my domain".

Comment: Ask your domain admin to enable that option

Comment: I think I'm listed as the owner of the Google site. Is it the same as domain admin? How a domain admin can enable this option? I solved this problem by copying my script to a new script and in this new script this option "Anyone, Even Anonymous" is available. Then I inserted this new script to the site as a a url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to let users in the domain to share the webapp with "Anyone, even anonymous", your domain Admin should do the following:

- Visit [Google Admin console](https://admin.google.com/).
- Select **Apps > G Suite > Settings for Drive and Docs > Sharing settings**.
- In **Sharing options > Sharing outside of [Your domain]**, select **ON**.

Beware, because of a [current bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764781), if you created the script when the sharing settings were **OFF**, you won't be able to share it outside the domain, even if you change that. The sharing settings are applied when the script is created, and those settings cannot be changed. A new script should be created for that (after enabling sharing outside the domain).

#### Reference:

- [Issue Tracker: Cannot select "Anyone, even anonymous" option in web app publication screen](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764781)

Comment: Sharing outside is on. Probably the problem caused by this bug you mentioned. Copying the script to a new one solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

** RESOLVED **
Hi guys,
This somehow misled me by choosing "User accessing the web app" under **Execute the app as** where it should be "ME"!

Only then then "Anyone, even Anonymous" will show up in the next dropdown. Took a while before I figured this out as I realized that Google needs to know the account who will execute the script. If its any user, then it will surely prompt the account login to where it should associate the "executor" of the script with. So if its always ME (your account) then it won't prompt anymore of any authentication.

This is where I can really mark this as RESOLVED!

[Deploy as Web App window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLBZR.png)

Comment: Why don't you post an answer to your own question, then?

Comment: I think I started on the wrong foot here.I think you may be commenting on my 1st line "This somehow misled me.." I'm not saying that the post misled me.What I meant was the option labeled "User accessing the web app" misled me.And the exclamation mark was a form of excitement and not to impose an offense to the op nor any posts.So for that,I apologize.This was the exact question I was looking for here when I was trying to resolve the same issue,and when I did,I thought it was just appropriate to post it here for other viewers to see how others have resolved it.But sure,noted on your insight.ty

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that comes across this and is using the new Apps Script IDE, I found that the option only exists when using the legacy IDE.

Comment: Saved hours for me!

Comment: This is NOT true. This option exists ... it's just called "Anyone" in the new IDE. If you can't see it, see other answers here for troubleshooting.