# Deployed web app with anonymous access privileges asks for login or gives error

Tags: google-apps-script

I set up a simple "Hello World" app that reads the url query, and set the deployment as follows:
[image: Deployment Settings]

While this is using my workdspace account, the code doesn't access any resources yet. But When i access the app on the URL in an incognito window I get a prompt to log into google. When I access it on a session with a different account (not from my work organization) logged in, I get this:

[image]

What could be wrong? The app's URL is: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby_FgMJNYgfoDW6eA1X7gWVDd1dFOR6dAQN6AV49QM0tcXseGtVlXNZC_Dc693dqBlK/exec?4567 (i tried adding the organization domain (/a/domain.com) but the only difference it did was that in incognito mode it added the domain suffix to the username field).

(Edit) code.gs content is:

```
function include(filename){
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
.getContent();
};
function doGet(e) {
asset_id = e.queryString;
webpagecontent = "start text " + asset_id + " end text.";
return HtmlService
.createTemplateFromFile('test.html')
.evaluate();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your sample code? Are you passing `4567` as an argument to your web app http get request?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it above. It's just a simple snippet of code (eventually I want to retrieve a row from a spreadsheet corresponding to the asset id and show it in html). It works when I'm logged on and I assume when someone else on the organization views it.

Comment: Hmm this could be it. I am assuming that having the deployment set to be accessible to anyone would mean that sharing is set accordingly, but knowing google there could be a setting elsewhere as well. I'll check and update this comment. Thank you @Ron M.

Comment: You can check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60987691/14606046

Comment: Just changed the script sharing privileges from the Drive app to "Anyone on the internet with the link can view" (the link here being the one to the source code, as it's the only one I could see there) and it didn't have any effect, same problem.

Comment: Thanks. The global "Sharing outside the org" setting is on for Drive (has been for years).  While that question is similar, I have no issue with choosing the appropriate access level (anyone even anonymous); the problem is that it's not working correctly even then.

Comment: Could you try creating a new script and deploying it anonymously. If that still doesn't work. You can file a bug in https://issuetracker.google.com/

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct and  the latest deployment url?

Comment: @TheMaster: yes. Updated the same deployment a few times to make sure the access settings are correct.

Comment: Try creating a new version for that deployment

Comment: @TheMaster: This worked! Thank you! I created a new script, put it in a public-accessible folder, and copied everything into it (including the deployment settings), opened the link in incognito to test, and sent it to a colleague to open, and it worked both times.

Comment: Hi, I highly recommend it if you could post your solution as an answer so that other people who encountered similar issues would be able to refer to your solution easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP resolved the issue by creating a new script, put it in a public-accessible folder, and copied everything into it (including the deployment settings),then opened the link in incognito to test